# Subscriber record not inserted when using Contact as Email Source in Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I have MC and SC connected using the MC Connector App, using the "Salesforce Data" entry, I inserted newly inserted Contacts straight into my Journey. I've noticed when I set the Default Address (in Journey Settings) to "Use email attribute from Contacts" then any new Contacts are not automatically added to the All Subscribers list, they also do not receive any comms.

Is this expected behavior? When set to "Use email attribute from Entry Source", the Contact is automatically added to the All Subscribers list if they dont exist already.

Comment: SC as ServiceCloud or Salescloud :D

Comment: Sorry, its Service Cloud

Comment: Contacts only get added to all subs list during an email send. Are your contacts failing when you use email from contact model?

Comment: @EazyE Yes, it’s only when I’ve set the journey to use email address from the Contact model instead of journey entry email. There’s an email that’s supposed to be sent as soon as the journey is started, but they never receive that email.

Comment: So are you injecting based of creation. If so the sync only happens every 15 mins. They may not exist in contact data yet

Comment: I dont think the mc sync really matters here, as the Contact wont be created merely be syncing objects across. It is only created when an email send is made.

Comment: It is definitely not made in the case of a 'Use email attribute from Contacts' configuration in the Journey.  I do not know what the difference is whether the email comes from Contact or Entry Source, but sends most certainly does not work at the moment unless that Contact has already been added to All Subscribers some other way.

Comment: The issue is the contact is failing out of the journey and not receiving the email, thus not added to all subs. In journey history dashboard due you see errors, similar to "data bound error"

Comment: @EazyE Nope, the only action I see is "Trigger: (Journey Name)"

Comment: @Mike If you use Journey Entry data as the Email Source instead of the Contact data model, the email will be sent and create the Subscriber if its not already in the system.

Comment: It appears journey history is behind. Are you injecting after creation? if so add a 30 min wait step for the sync to sync over the contact so they exist in contact data

Comment: @DeploymentFailure Right, but it does not do so with Contact Email as the Email Source.  This is current behavior and as of last communication with Marketing Cloud support (a few months back) this is expected/current behavior.  I had to implement some workarounds for this behavior in my integration for a client that had Journeys configured with Contact Email Address - it just does not add to All Subscribers with this configuration.

Comment: @Mike as a consequence of not adding to all Subs, I suspect not receiving the email is also expected right?

Comment: @DeploymentFailure Yep.  This is how it was originally brought to my attention -- a customer brought it to my attention their emails were not being sent/received.  A numbers of calls with Marketing Cloud support teams later, and this 'feature' of Contact Email Journey configurations was revealed.  As mentioned below, I was unable to get a clear answer as to whether this is intended behavior or if it is a deficiency that might be eventually fixed, I just ended up with the information that this is how the system is currently working.

Comment: Again the reason the email wasn't received is because it errored out of the journey, perhaps journey history has caught up to help provide clarity

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it expected behavior, but it is certainly current behavior.

I have gone through Marketing Cloud support to verify.  They were non committal on whether this is intended or unintended and planned for future enhancement - I was just able to have confirmed that this is the behavior.

MC Connect creates Contacts but does not currently add them to any Subscriber list.  Journey entry does not automatically create a Subscriber record.  Email sends (and other communications reliant upon Subscriber) fail for these Contacts dropped into a Journey that aren't part of a Subscriber list.

The only work around I can see is to either use the email from entry source, as you have noted, or to somehow add the Contact to a Subscriber list manually which I have accomplished in my own integration via SOAP Api prior to sending the Contact through a Journey.